# Thor's hammer left in a elevator...could I move it?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

If Thor left his hammer on the floor of an elevator and then he stepped off the elevator, would I then be able to send the elevator to different floors?  Thereby moving the hammer in a vertical direction?

Comment: When Thor dropped the hammer on the floor of the Helicarrier in the first Avengers movie, the Helicarrier didn't have any problems staying in the air.

Comment: Same question asked on sister site: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73729/can-you-pick-up-thors-hammer

Comment: @MrLister thanks.  I haven't actually seen that movie.  :-)

Comment: Everything moves depending on frame of reference, Thor can just lock hammer's position in chosen frame.

Comment: When Thor put his hammer on the ground, does Earth stop moving?

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski see, that's what I want to know. But seeing the down votes I received, such questions are not to be trifled with.

Answer (score 9):

It's worth remembering that Mjolnir's inscription says:

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.

The operative word here is *hold*, not *lift*.

In this sequence, you can see Mjolnir on the ground on the helicarrier, but it doesn't have any problem maintaining altitude:

In another sequence, Thor hangs Mjolnir on a simple coat-hook:

Thus, the mechanism here isn't mass related and so there's no reason an elevator couldn't lift the hammer.

Comment: So, does that mean by me pressing the buttons of the elevator I have indeed moved the hammer?

Comment: You seem to assume that Mjolnir is simply guided by an algorithm when it more closely resembles a pet

Comment: @Valorum I assume nothing regarding Mjolnir.  Having never read the comics, I was genuinely curious on how a mortal such as myself could ever move Thor's hammer.  That's all.

Comment: @cbmeeks - You can move it by becoming worthy

Comment: @Valorum see my dilemma? By moving the elevator, I am indirectly moving the hammer even though I am not worthy.  That's what I want to know.

Comment: @cbmeeks - The frame of reference seems to be "where Thor left it and what he intended". If he wants it to remain static, it can't be moved. If he places it down on something moving, it can move. It's a smart device

Comment: Obviously, the coat rack is Worthy.

Comment: @Valorum AH!  So, by that logic, if Thor left the hammer in the elevator knowing it would NOT be static, I could then remove the entire elevator and take it anywhere I want.  Meaning, I could move the hammer *anywhere* simply because Thor thought the elevator would remain inside the building.

Comment: @cbmeeks - I would assume that Mjolnir, as the product of an advanced civilisation would be aware that lifts go up and down, not sideways onto the back of a lorry

Comment: I don't think that you can find loopholes in Mjolnir's enchantment. It can likely read intention and if someone were to try to exploit an elevator's motion, I doubt it would allow it. I think Mjolnir will move only according to Thor's intent or by the actions of someone more powerful than the enchantment.

Comment: @TBear: One attempt at a loophole: Elevators, helicarriers, ... **machines** can lift Mjolnir, but people cannot. So an **empty** Iron Man suit (remotely operated) should be able to lift Mjolnir. But what about a suit with Tony Stark in it **while it is still remotely controlled**? And what if Tony controls the suit himself? Mjolnir isn't exclusive to Thor (remember that Vision wielded him too, but others could not, even in emergencies where Thor would've obviously allowed them to wield it for a second)

Comment: @Flater citation needed. When have we seen that a machine could lift Mjolnir (note SHEILD could lift it with trucks in Thor 1)? When did Thor give permission to someone to lift it? Also, Vision has an infinity stone in his forehead, which I believe makes him more powerful than the enchantment. Either that or he is worthy to rule Asgard.

Comment: @TBear: So do you think the Avengers' helicarrier never changed altitude while Mjolnir was on board? Because that would most certainly count as a machine lifting Mjolnir. Your focus on Thor's _permission_ seems to imply that Thor can allow someone to wield the hammer, but when has that ever happened, where Thor's decision was the deciding factor?

Comment: Note "Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor" nothing in that says anything about unworthy people being unable to lift or hold the hammer; it just says that worthy people holding the hammer will have Thor's powers — so I'm not sure you can really draw these conclusions from it, at least not on such a literal level as to make a distinction between "hold" and "lift".

Answer (score 4):

According to the comics, yes.

As seen as early as *JOURNEY INTO MYSTERY* #106 (cover dated July 1964), machines can move Thor's hammer without difficulty:

[image]

So, an elevator would be able to move the hammer. As others have noted, *wielding* the hammer would be another matter entirely....

Comment: It makes me wonder why Tony wasn't able to lift the hammer with his gloves ON (*Avengers* movie). And, why Stan Lee wasn't able to pull the hammer using Truck (*Thor* movie).

Comment: OK, this makes the most sense to me as I never read the comic.  Not sure why I'm getting downvotes?  I thought it was a legit question but I guess I ticked off some Thor fanatics.

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski - I would say that Tony's gloves were (among other things) boosting his strength, but it was still Tony trying to lift the hammer, essentially in his own hand. If he was remote-controlling the armor at that point, it would be more questionable....

Comment: @RDFozz I question if remote control would count.  If I remote control a car, I am still driving the car.  I'm just not in it.  I would imagine Iron Man's suit would be the same.  Meaning, Tony being inside the suit wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @cbmeeks - I agree that a remote controlled suit of armor would have the same difficulties as occupied armor in moving/wielding the hammer; I simply recognize that others might argue the point.

Answer (score 1):

## Maybe Not. Maybe Yes.

In the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie, we saw this conversation:

> Steve Rogers: The rules have changed.
>   Tony Stark: We're dealing with something new.
>   Steve Rogers: Well, the Vision's artificial intelligence.
>   Tony Stark: A machine.
>   Steve Rogers: So it doesn't count.
>   Tony Stark: No. It's not like a person lifting the hammer.
>   Steve Rogers: Right. Different rules for us.
>   Tony Stark: Nice guy, but artificial.
>   Steve Rogers: Thank you.
>   Thor: If he can wield the hammer, he can keep the Mind Stone. It's safe with the Vision and these days, safe is in short supply.
>   Steve Rogers: But if you put the hammer in an elevator...
>   Tony Stark: It would still go up.
>   Steve Rogers: Elevator's not worthy.
>   Thor: I'm going to miss these little talks of ours.

Here, Thor dodged the question and we never really saw a machine lifting the hammer:

- When the hammer was on-board helicarrier in *Avengers* movie, we never see the helicarrier go up.
- Talking about Vision (as per concerns of Tony and Steve), he can be considered more than machine because he has consciousness thanks to Mind Stone and he is using this well such that he is worthy. Otherwise, Thor would simply be called ignorant for such important thing.

However, we saw few instances when machines couldn't lift it:

- In *Age of Ultron*, Tony and Rhodes both used their gloves (machine) to lift the hammer, but it didn't work.
- In *Thor*, Stan Lee tried to drag the hammer using a truck, but the attempt failed.

But, again, I would say that we don't have enough data as there are other factors at play (like weight; although it doesn't have enough weight to crush Loki, it can still be difficult for truck or Tony's glove repulsors).

Comment: Those are good points!  Also, what if instead of moving it we dug under it?  Would it fall or float in the air?  That's controlled movement if it falls but you could only move vertically down.  And for only so far.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basing my answer on Marvel comics rather than the MCU.
There have been numerous incidents of Thor losing his hammer due to it either being trapped in something in which it could not break out, or being transported far enough from him that it could not return to him before reverting to its base form. 
(The original storyline required that Thor keeps in contact with his hammer on a regular basis or he would revert to Dr. Blake and the Hammer would become a stick.)
Short version, yes the elevator could move based on many decades of precedent.